# Images not displaying in hbs/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a simple web app with NodeJs and express-handlebars .
But Images are not displaying properly  in my html page which I'm rendering using handlebars.

Below is my app structure

MyApp is root folder

```
-images
-views
  -layouts
    -main.hbs
  -home.hbs
-index.js
-package.json
```

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gin64.png)

My **index.js** contains below code

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

//Setting default layout and extension name
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'main',
extname: '.hbs'
}));

//providing path for images 
app.use(express.static("images"));

//Setting view engine 
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//get method for landing page
app.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
  res.render('landing')
})

//get method for home page
app.get('/home',(req,res) =>{
  res.render('home');
})
//Staring server
app.listen(8080,() =>{
   console.log("Server started successfully on port 8080");
});
```

And **home.hbs** contains is as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/home/vishu/Desktop/WebTest/ECom/images/apple.jpg"  alt="Apple product set">
</body>
</html>
```

What should i do to fix the above problem

Comment: Your image `src` is not a path on your server's hard drive, it's a URL (the browser cannot see the server's HD for obvious reasons, it must request the image via HTTP, just like the HTML document). You have set your images directory as the root for static files, so it should be `<img src="/apple.jpg">` (note that you probably want to create a `public` folder instead, move your images folder in there and use `src="/images/apple.jpg"` so that you can also link to static CSS and JS files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let options = {
            dotfiles: "ignore", //allow, deny, ignore
            etag: true,
            extensions: ["htm", "html"],
            index: false, //to disable directory indexing
            maxAge: "7d",
            redirect: false,
            setHeaders: function (res: any, path: any, stat: any) {
                //add this header to all static responses
                res.set("x-timestamp", Date.now());
            }
        };

//process.cwd will fetch from the current working directory and serve images over the server
app.use(express.static(`${process.cwd()}/images`, options));
//it will set the html path that would get served from /views 
app.set('views', express.static(process.cwd() + '/views'));
//it will set the engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

For image url get the path by using hosted images on server.

```
//BASE URL
`${BASE.URL}/images/Pamlogo.png`
```

```
Give it a try, All the best (yes)
```